# how to get python 3 to use ENTER as an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i get the enter key to work in this situation? I tried searching for it, but maybe i'm wording it wrong.
also, how would i get the else statement to work in this particular situation?

thank you

```
import random

def roll_dice():
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    print("You rolled a %n " % roll)



def main():
    input("Hit ENTER to roll a single dice: ")
    roll_dice()
    else:
        print("exiting program.")

main()
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to store input in a variable. Let it be `enter`.
User will hit enter and you will check if it was enter or not.
If input was an empty string then it is okay!

```
import random

def roll_dice():
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    print("You rolled a %d " % roll)



def main():
    enter = input("Hit ENTER to roll a single dice: ")
    if enter == '':  # hitting enter == ''  empty string
        roll_dice()
    else:
        print("exiting program.")
        exit()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this, would I usually do, is something like this:

```
if input == "":
    roll_dice()
```

I'm not sure if thats what you are looking for, though :3

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
if not input("Hit ENTER to roll a single dice: "):
    roll_dice()
else:
    print("exiting program.")
```

Also use a **while** loop instead, to ask user multiple times:

```
import random

def roll_dice():
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    print("You rolled a {} ".format(roll))

def main():
    while True:
        if not input("Hit ENTER to roll a single dice: "):
            roll_dice()
        else:
            print("exiting program.")
            break

main()
```

If `input()` is non empty it will exit the program.

Comment: ahh i see. it took me a minute to understand the "if not input". I was thinking of ENTER as an input, but i guess its really the absence of an input... i had it backwards.

Comment: Oh! it's the negation, if input has nothing it will ignore in this case and call the function.